# How to store parameters in a map using DataTable in cucumber Java

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber, bdd

I have a feature file, and in one of the steps, I'm trying to pass parameters to the step definitions using the format below:

```
Then the user's name and password should be displayed as what we expected
  |Name |Password|
  |aaa  |11|
  |bbb  |22|
```

Then for the steps, I was tying to store the parameters I passed in into a map using:

```java
List <Map <String, String> expected =dataTable.asMaps(String.class, String.class);
```

Because in this way I can compare this with the actual result (also stored in a map).

My question is: Can I store the parameters in the feature file into a map in the way I described?  I'm asking because my code failed to compile.

Comment: You are missing a  `>` right after `List<Map<String, String>`.

Comment: "_my code failed to compile_" - you can [edit] your question to show the full text of the compilation error message.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at your code, it would be difficult to pin point why it is failing. However, I tried the exact scenario you posted with datatable and it works for me. Please check this gif to see the implementation
https://nocodebdd.live/datatable

I have also created NoCodeBDD, which allows you to automate BDDs without code and in minutes. Would love to get some feedback from you and other BDD enthusiasts. Basic version is free and you can download it from https://www.nocodebdd.com/download